ERROR: root: Error fetching patient details: PatientView.html
I'm trying to create a simple webpage using Flask. I have written code to fetch data from a MySQL database, but the code is not working, and I keep getting the error:
Error:
root: Error fetching patient details: PatientView.html.
Here is the Python code I've written:
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, flash
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_login import UserMixin, LoginManager, login_user, logout_user, current_user, login_required
from datetime import datetime
import pymysql
import logging
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'Krish'

# Configuring the Flask app
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/medical'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Initialize the database engine
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:@localhost/medical')

# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# Initialize Flask-Login
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'home'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    session: Session = db.session
    return session.get(Login, int(user_id))

class Patients(db.Model):
    Patient_Id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    Address = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    Phone_Number = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    Email = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    Health_Problem = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    Payment = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    Gender = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)

@login_required
def user():
    return render_template('User.html')

@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    return render_template('Admin.html')

@app.route('/PIF', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def PIF():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            id = int(request.form.get('id'))
            name = request.form.get('name')
            address = request.form.get('address')
            email = request.form.get('email')
            health_problem = request.form.get('health_problem')
            payment = int(request.form.get('payment'))
            contact = request.form.get('phone')
            gender = request.form.get('gender')
            new_patient = Patients(
                Patient_Id=id, Name=name, Email=email, Payment=payment,
                Address=address, Phone_Number=contact, Gender=gender, Health_Problem=health_problem
            )
            db.session.add(new_patient)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('New Patient Record Added', 'success')
        except Exception as e:
            flash(f'Input Invalid or Error: {e}', 'danger')
    return render_template('Patient Information.html')

@app.route('/Patient_Details')
@login_required
def Patient_Details():
    try:
        patients = Patients.query.all()
        return render_template('PatientView.html', values=patients)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'Error fetching patient details: {e}')
        print(e)
        flash('An error occurred while fetching patient details.', 'danger')
        return redirect(url_for('admin'))  # Redirect to a safe page

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=True)


And here is the corresponding html code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Patient Details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Patient_Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Phone_Number</th>
            <th>Health_Problem</th>
            <th>Payment</th>
            <th>Gender</th>
        </tr>
        {% for patient in values %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ patient.Patient_Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Address }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Email }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Phone_Number }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Health_Problem }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Payment }}</td>
            <td>{{ patient.Gender }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>

Please help me!

Remove the try/except and hen [edit] the question to include the complete error traceback please.

what is the exact error(error traceback) that you are getting. kindly log it and paste it here.
